# React-native going back from a nested navigation container does not work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am creating a nested navigation container in react-native and the stack looks like this:

-Main Navigation Container:
- Home
- Market Navigation Container:
- Market
- Cart
- About

When I go to home or about and go back, it works properly. However, when I go back from Market or cart (Which I expect to go to the Home page) it shows an error saying:

```
The action 'POP' with payload {"count":1} was not handled by any navigator.
Is there any screen to go back to?
This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.
```

This is my code for the main navigation container:

```
  <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
         <Stack.Screen options={myOptions} name="Home" component={Home} />
         <Stack.Screen
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
            name="MarketNavigation"
            component={MarketNavigation}
          />
         <Stack.Screen options={myOptions} name="About" component={About} />
       </Stack.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
```

And this is my code for the market navigation:

```
  <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} independent={true}>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            options={myOptions}
            name="Market"
            component={Market}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            options={myOptions}
            name="Cart"
            component={Cart}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this when navigating to nested navigator using "screen" option like this:

```
navigation.navigate('Root', {
  screen: 'Settings'
})
```

;

As mentioned in the documentation:

> By default, when you navigate a screen in the nested navigator, the
> specified screen is used as the initial screen and the initial route
> prop on the navigator is ignored.

To solve this you should use "initial: false" like so:

```
navigation.navigate('Root', {
  screen: 'Settings',
  initial: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add in the code where you navigate from Home to MarketNavigation and back?

Comment: The back button is added by default when I create Navigation Container and create Stack.

Comment: Only other thing that seems weird is the NavigationContainer in market navigation. You only need 1 NavigationContainer at the root level, try removing the NavigationContainer in your market navigation?